# Vertical alignment in sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How would I align items in a sidebar like this:

See image

[image: 1]

my main problems are the formatting for the footer being fixed to the bottom and the main sidebar container overflowing and scrolling but still being between the sidebar header and the sidebar bottom element text container, so not overlapping either while having that element be scrollable without the whole sidebar scrolling

what i have so far:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 bg-dark text-white" style="height: 100vh; width:250px;">
            <!-- <div class="col bg-primary">
                test
            </div>

            <div class="col bg-danger">
                test 2
            </div>

            <div class="col bg-primary" style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">
                test 3
            </div> -->

            <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-start mb-3">
                <div class="p-2 bg-primary">
                    Flex item 1
                </div>

                <div class="p-2 bg-danger flex-grow-1">
                    Flex item 2
                </div>
                <div class="p-2 bg-primary" style="position:fixed; bottom:0;">
                    Flex item 3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col bg-secondary text-white">
            main body
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-secondary text-white">
            main body
        </div>
    </div> -->
</div>
```

using bootstrap 5.3.0 alpha1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example of how to create a full page layout with a container that should scroll on overflow using Bootstrap V5.3.

Read the docs if you like to learn how it works.

- [Read about `flex-grow-1`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/flex/#grow-and-shrink) or if you're new to flex [start here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).
- [Learn how overflow works.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp)

```css
nav {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
 background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row gx-0">
      <nav class="col-4 p-2 d-flex flex-column gap-1">
        <div class="">
          <h5>
            Sidebar header
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          Some content
        </div>
        <div class="">
          Some other content
        </div>
        <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
          sidebar scroll
          <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> end sidebar scroll
        </div>
        <div class="">
          Sidebar footer
        </div>
      </nav>
      <main class="col">
        main body
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**If `<main>` should also `overflow:scroll` at `100vh`**.

Add in CSS:

```
main {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

and in HTML:

```
<main class="col overflow-auto">
```

**If `<main>` *can* grow beyond the viewport height and you want `<nav>` to grow along with it.**

You could wrap the content inside `col-4` in an absolute positioned container that fills `col-4` and therefore let it grow beyond `100vh` `height` while keeping the overflow scroll if `<main>` is smaller, for example:

```css
nav {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

nav #overflow-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

main {
  background: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row gx-0">
      <nav class="col-4 position-relative">
        <div class="p-2 d-flex flex-column gap-1" id="overflow-container">
          <div class="">
            <h5>
              Sidebar header
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            Some content
          </div>
          <div class="">
            Some other content
          </div>
          <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
            sidebar scroll
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> end sidebar scroll
          </div>
          <div class="">
            Sidebar footer
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <main class="col">
        main body
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**If `<nav>` and `<main>` should stack vertically at a smaller screen size.**

In the HTML make `.row` a `flex-column` by default and a flex row on the medium breakpoint with `flex-md-row`. Then change `col-4` to `col-md-4`.

In the CSS add a media query, using Bootstrap's medium breakpoint width.

Note: Snippet below is based on the example above with an absolute positioned container, but the same logic can also be applied to the other examples.

```css
nav {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}

main {
  background: lightyellow;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  nav #overflow-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid px-0">
    <div class="row gx-0 flex-column flex-md-row">
      <nav class="col-md-4 position-relative">
        <div class="p-2 d-flex flex-column gap-1" id="overflow-container">
          <div class="">
            <h5>
              Sidebar header
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="">
            Some content
          </div>
          <div class="">
            Some other content
          </div>
          <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
            sidebar scroll
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br> end sidebar scroll
          </div>
          <div class="">
            Sidebar footer
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <main class="col">
        main body
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you! if i could ask another question - i have 2 nav tab buttons in the sidebar that will change the layout of the main body content depending on what's pressed. I'm having an issue with having both the 3 and 4 column layout. the sidebar and one other column stay but the other 1 or 2 columns move under the sidebar. i can edit the post and show what i have if you wouldn't mind taking a look

Comment: @420stackgod69 Please create a new question with your code to keep this Q+A intact. You can add a comment with the link of the new question here, if you like me to see it.